# How to synchronize Map between one r/w Thread and one read-only Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, dictionary, synchronized

I have a synchronized Map (via `Collections.synchronizedMap()`) that is read and updated by Thread A.  Thread B accesses the Map only via `Map.keySet()` (read-only).

How should I synchronize this?  The [docs say](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) that keySet() (for a Collections.synchronizedMap) "Needn't be in synchronized block".  I can put Thread A's read/write access within a synchronized block, but is that even necessary?

I guess it seems odd to me to even use a synchronized Map, or a synchronized block, if Map.keySet doesn't need to be synchronized (according to the docs link above)...

**Update:** I missed that iteration of the keySet must be synchronized, even though retrieving the keySet does not require sync.  Not particularly exciting to have the keySet without being able to look through it, so end result = synchronization required.  Using a ConcurrentHashMap instead.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık nope.  General Java concurrency question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a truly read/write versus read/only locking `Map` wrapper, you can take a look at the wrapper the `Collections` uses for `synchronizedMap()` and replace all of the `synchronized` statements with a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.  This is a good bit of work.  Instead, you should consider switching to using a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) which does all of the right things there.

In terms of `keySet()`, it doesn't need to be in a `synchronized` block because it is already being `synchronized` by the `Collections.synchronizedMap()`.  The Javadocs is just pointing out that if you are iterating through the map, you need to synchronize on it because you are doing multiple operations, but you don't need to synchronize when you are getting the `keySet()` which is wrapped in a `SynchronizedSet` class which does its own synchronization.

Lastly, your question seemed to be implying that you don't need to synchronize on something if you are just reading from it.  You have to remember that synchronization not only protects against race conditions but also ensures that the data is properly shared by each of the processors.  Even if you are accessing a `Map` as read-only, you still need to synchronize on it if any other thread is updating it.

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to say, but `keySet()` *isn't* a "copy of the keys in the `Map`" (it's a live view), and it must not be to not have to be in the synchronized block.  If it were truly a copy and you didn't obtain it within the synchronized block, then your iteration could be over stale data.  To ensure it were fresh you'd have to include the `keySet()` method in the synchronization.

Comment: I knew it was typically @Mark but I didn't take a look at the code.  Now that I do I see that it wraps it in a `SynchronizedSet`.  I'll change my answer.  THanks.

Comment: So, to clarify, if I use ConcurrentHashMap, do I still need to synchronize access (r/w or just read), or is synchronization handled by CHM itself?  And, what object is used for the lock in each case?

Comment: If you use `ConcurrentHashMap` you don't need to do any synchronization.  The class does it all.  It was designed from the ground up to be a high performance reentrant map @eric.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for the clarification.  And re: your edit about synchronizing even for read-only cases, I understand (after some SO digging) that read-only does not mean no sync needed.  It was mainly me missing the point made by the docs that iteration requires synchronization (see my comment on @MarkPeters' answer).  Will edit my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

The docs are telling you how to properly synchronize multi-step operations that need to be atomic, in this case iterating over the map:

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
      ...
Set s = m.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
      ...
synchronized(m) {  // Synchronizing on m, not s!
    Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
    while (i.hasNext())
        foo(i.next());
}
```

Note how the *actual iteration* must be in a synchronized block.  The docs are just saying that it doesn't matter if *obtaining* the `keySet()` is in the synchronized block, because it's a *live view* of the `Map`.  If the keys in the map change between the reference to the key set being obtained and the beginning of the synchronized block, the key set will reflect those changes.

And by the way, the docs you cite are only for a `Map` returned by `Collections.synchronizedMap`.  The statement does *not necessarily* apply to all `Map`s.

Comment: Very good point, I missed that the iteration of the keySet must be synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

The docs are correct. The map returned from `Collections.synchronizedMap()` will properly wrap synchronized around all calls sent to the original `Map`.  However, the set impl returned by keySet() does not have the same property, so you must ensure it is read under the same lock.

Without this synchronization, there is no guarantee that Thread B will ever see any update made by Thread A.

You might want to investigate `ConcurrentHashMap`. It provides useful semantics for exactly this use case. Iterating over a collection view in CHM ([like `keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet%28%29)) gives useful concurrent behavior ("weakly consistent" iterators). You will traverse all keys from the state of the collection at iteration and you may or may not see changes after the iterator was created.